# ARC Welder Warnings

Tags: google-chrome-arc

I keep getting the following warnings when trying to install various apps. Would anyone know how to fix these?

```
There were warnings when trying to install this extension:
Unrecognized manifest key 'arc_metadata'.
'accessibilityFeatures.read' is not allowed for specified platform.
```

Answer (score 1):

Per https://developer.chrome.com/apps/accessibilityFeatures

> Important: This API works only on Chrome OS.

This is a warning you will see when running on non-Chrome OS.  It is benign, and accessibilityFeatures will just not be used on these platforms.

Comment: Hmm okay, I get no other warnings, yet none of my apps are running.

Comment: There are probably warnings or error in the logs: https://developer.chrome.com/apps/getstarted_arc#bestpractices  also if there are specific problems with an app you're working on you should file a bug to let the team know: http://goo.gl/megdlG